# joomla htaccess RewriteRule issue

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect, joomla

i have a redirect in my htaccess which works perfectly in joomla before i swicth on SEF URLS

RewriteRule ^m/(.*) /index.php?option=com_seemail&view=mail&guid=$1&itemid=102

however when i switch on SEF URLS then it no longer works - im directed to  /home/uncategorised/welcome instead

this is my htaccess :

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^m/(.*) /index.php?option=com_seemail&view=mail&guid=$1&itemid=102

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f 
RewriteRule ^apply$ /index.php?option=com_loans&view=apply&Itemid=102 [R=301,L,QSA]



RewriteBase /
DirectoryIndex index.php

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} mosConfig_[a-zA-Z_]{1,21}(=|\%3D) [OR]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} base64_encode.*\(.*\) [OR]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (\<|%3C).*script.*(\>|%3E) [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} GLOBALS(=|\[|\%[0-9A-Z]{0,2}) [OR]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} _REQUEST(=|\[|\%[0-9A-Z]{0,2})
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php [F,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/index.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (/|\.php|\.html|\.htm|\.feed|\.pdf|\.raw|/[^.]*)$  [NC]
RewriteRule (.*) index.php
RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization},L]
```

can anyone help please ?

Answer (score 0):

```
RewriteRule ^apply$ /index.php?option=com_loans&view=apply&Itemid=102 [R=301,L,QSA]
```

based on the above line of code, if there is nothing after "apply" in the url, it should redirect to `/index.php?option=com_loans&view=apply&Itemid=102` and stop looking at other rules for the said case.

As you said it is redirecting that means it is working.

Can you manually open the `<yourdomain.com>/index.php?option=com_loans&view=apply&Itemid=102`

If it opens and the url is sef, copy the sef url after the domain and replace `/index.php?option=com_loans&view=apply&Itemid=102` with that in the RewriteRule.

May be that should work.

Comment: Hi there, thanks for the reply but that redirect works fine - its the RewriteRule ^m/(.*) one that does not ! tnx

Comment: Can you please quote an example of the url that was working before sef was switched on for RewriteRule ^m/(.*) ?

Comment: hi this url was working : m/7af625e8215d31b0298b8699db6c7761  (it was redirecting to index.php?option=com_seemail&view=mail&guid=7af625e8215d31b0298b8699db6c7761&itemid=102 - however now it does not work ! tnx